# RSA Encryption in iPhone using existing Public Key and MOD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have RSA Encryption implemented in Android using BouncyCastle API. I have Public Key and MOD which I want to use for iPhone app. The only thing I am concern with using RSA encryption is the encryption part.

Server is same for both Android and iPhone app and has the Private Key to decrypt the data.

Kindly, explain how can I implement the RSAEncrypter in iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code might might help or give u some idea.. :
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1795474?start=0&tstart=0